# What's the translation of a "soundalike" in French?

Tags: traduction

A soundalike [is](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/through-ticket#:%7E:text=a%20ticket%20that%20you%20can,or%20planes%20on%20the%20way):

> a person or thing that closely resembles another in sound, especially someone whose voice or style of speaking or singing is very similar to that of a famous person.

What's the translation of a *soundalike* in French? I barely see any occurrences of "sosie sonore" or "sosie vocal" on Google so I wonder whether there exits a more widely used translation.

Comment: "Sosie vocal" was my first intuition here. Maybe there is no one word solution to this in French. There need not be, in the sense that words in various languages don't necessarily have 1:1 exact translations.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas trop comment tu es arrivé à la conclusion que "sosie vocal" avait peu de résultats sur google. Pour une personne en tout cas, c'est le mot tout trouvé. Peut-être parce que le concept de sosie vocal est plutôt rare de manière générale? C'est pas souvent qu'une personne a la même voix qu'une célébrité.

Comment: Pour compléter les commentaires précédents, c'est le terme habituel quand il s'agit de chanteurs, par exemple. [« The Voice ». Michael Jackson, Bob Marley, Elvis… ces sosies vocaux qui ont bluffé les coachs.](https://programmetv.ouest-france.fr/divers/divertissement/the-voice-kids-m159024042/the-voice-michael-jackson-bob-marley-elvis-ces-sosies-vocaux-qui-ont-bluffe-les-coachs-ec5a1372-e045-11ed-85f8-8628b3aa7259)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat c'est une passion de la culture de langue anglaise et surtout américaine 1/ d'étiqueter compulsivement le moindre phénomène ou fait (de société, naturel, etc.) par un mot souvent valise, aidé par la plasticité de la langue ; 2/ générer du spectacle autour de célébrités du spectacle - les sosies en sont un exemple. C'est beaucoup moins le cas en francophonie. Je ne trouve pas étonnant qu'un Américain puisse être étonné (!) du peu de résultats sur ces termes dans Google en français.

Comment: @guillaume31Le français est aussi "plastique" que l'anglais. Il suffit d'oser.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that *sosie vocal* is the best approximation here, esp. if what is asked for is an expression that can function as a name for *someone whose voice ... is very similar to that of [another person]*. It doesn't look like French has an exact 1:1 word mapping for this.

Answer (score 2):

I would use "**imitateur vocal**" ou "**double vocal**" (could be "vocal double" in English though).

Comment: Oui, mais un _imitateur_ ou un _double_ imite consciemment, alors que _soundalike_ peut être une coincidence fortuite.

Comment: @Frank Peut-être que "**imitateur vocal involontaire**" ou "**double vocal involontaire**" irait mieux? :)

Comment: Ca devient trop compliqué :-)

Comment: @Frank Oui, sans doute. Mais bon, à l'OP de voir. C'est tout de même une solution :P

Comment: Je ne pense pas puisque ceux-là seraient: voice impressionist.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, c'est ce que j'essayais de dire: à mon avis, dans _soundalike_ il n'y a pas la notion _d'intentionalité_ qu'on trouve dans _imitateur_ ou _double_.

Answer (score 1):

Une *[voix](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voix) semblable*, par métonymie de la voix pour le/la chanteur/chanteuse... j'imagine que ça pourrait être « similaire ».

Dans des domaines techniques, en adjectif on a, un peu différemment, « à consonance semblable ».

> [Méthode de test pour déterminer si la marque nominative proposée est
> à présentation et à consonance semblables](https://www.canada.ca/fr/sante-canada/services/medicaments-produits-sante/rapports-publications/medeffet-canada/ligne-directrice-intention-industrie-examen-marques-nominatives-medicament.html#a23) / [Testing of Proposed
> Brand Names for Look-alike Sound-alike Attributes](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/drugs-health-products/reports-publications/medeffect-canada/guidance-document-industry-review-drug-brand-names.html#a23) (Santé Canada)

Answer (score -2):

French does not provide for a metonymic term, by which the particular characteristic gives rise to a term for the person.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/crach%C3%A9/1)) **craché** II.− Adj., fig. et fam. [P. réf. à la technique du crachis qui souligne les traits] **Très ressemblant**.
>
> - Le portrait d'Hubert y est mal fait (...); il a l'air d'un ventilateur; − ma parole! d'un ventilateur tout craché (Gide, Paludes,1895, p. 127).
> - **Être le portrait (tout) craché de qqn**. Ressembler beaucoup à quelqu'un. Il est tout le portrait craché de son grand-père (Zola, Joie de vivre,1884, p. 858).

The following references show that this adjective can be used more generally than for just faces or bodily appearance.

([Les temps modernes](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_temps_modernes/BdTp7FlZvaMC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22tout+crach%C3%A9e%22&dq=%22tout+crach%C3%A9e%22&printsec=frontcover)) La Bulgarie tout crachée , dit Bettina ; elle désapprouva de la tête , attrapa son verre et but une grande gorgée : Ah , que c'est bon l'alcool !

([La Kahéna de la courtille - Derri Berkani · 2002](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Kah%C3%A9na_de_la_courtille/74FcAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22tout+crach%C3%A9e%22&dq=%22tout+crach%C3%A9e%22&printsec=frontcover) ) Le langage mis à part , c'est ma soeur Louisa tout crachée.

([Plein-songe - Perle Rasoloarijao Raminoarivelo](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Plein_songe/BsYdAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22tout+crach%C3%A9e%22&dq=%22tout+crach%C3%A9e%22&printsec=frontcover)) acques était stupéfait : c'était Léa tout crachée ! Les mêmes cheveux lisses , brillants et noirs de jais , Les mêmes yeux perçants qui semblaient vous manger , Le visage , le même , affectant quel sourire ! Le même rire d'enfant fait ...

([Grand Dictionnaire Français-Italien Composé Sur Les ... - Francesco d' Alberti de Villeneuve · 1828](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Grand_Dictionnaire_Fran%C3%A7ais_Italien_Com/hxtUAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22tout+crach%C3%A9e%22&pg=PA1015&printsec=frontcover)) Etre ou paraître la même chose tout crachée . Egli par suo padre pretto e sputato . C'est son père tout craché

- C'est la voix tout crachée de X
- Il/elle a la voix tout crachée de X
- Son langage est celui tout craché de X
- La façon de parler tout craché de X

Comment: Une référence pour _voix tout crachée_? Pour le moment, les références citées ne mentionnent pas une utilisation idiomatique dans le cas d'une _voix_. On peut donc supposer que _voix tout crachée_ est abusif, n'existe pas, n'est pas recommandable... Il faut absolument une _référence_ exacte.

Comment: @Frank *Sa voix tout crachée* n'est en effet ni idiomatique ni surtout grammatical. Une seule référence pour *sa voix tout**e** crachée* [ici](https://books.google.fr/books?id=foM6DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT201&lpg=PT201&dq=%22voix+toute+crach%C3%A9e%22&source=bl&ots=74XvNsPuTS&sig=ACfU3U0Fm99oQ7hnlHzcmdw5lC_qYRRddw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiluvLUkKeAAxWETKQEHS7jBDgQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=snippet&q=%22voix%20toute%20crach%C3%A9e%22&f=false), Mapp & Lucia, 2
d'Edward Frederic Benson.

Comment: @jlliagre En plus, le TLFi mentionne explicitement _la technique du crachis_ et le _portrait_, qui sont clairement des techniques d'art _visuel_, rien à avoir avec le domaine des sons. Les exemples cités après sont tellement généraux et abstraits qu'ils reflètent évidemment un usage _faux et déplorable_ par rapport au TLFi.

Comment: Note: je n'ai _pas_ moinssoyé cette réponse.

Comment: Il faut un substantif, pas un adjectif.

Comment: @Lambie The tags say "traduction", the text asks for a "translation".

Comment: Translation of a **noun**, not an adjective. Do you not understand my very simple comment?

Comment: @Lambie **What has been asked** is simply a **translation**; it can be anything that seems suitable, anything idiomatic. You'd choose a noun preferably, if there is one, but there is none.

Comment: @LPH Pourquoi ne corriges-tu pas la faute d'accord de l'adverbe *tout* devant *crachée*?

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne considère pas cette orthographe comme une faute, ou plutôt je ne peux pas décider. Il existe un grand nombre de cas récents avec cette orthographe (≃ 140 : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tout%20crach%C3%A9e%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr -  ≃ 280 : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22toute%20crach%C3%A9e%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

Comment: Objection accordée. Cette variante est effectivement courante.